# Claiming the provisioned storage

Tags: 11.10, server, disk, storage, disk-usage

I created a ubuntu server vm with 64GB provisioned storage. I remember that I specified 30GB to be used for the vm. When I do `df -h`, I get

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/analysis--db-root<br/>
                       28G   25G  904M  97% /
udev                  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 793M  228K  793M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1             228M   45M  171M  21% /boot
```

The disk is almost full, how can I use my other 30GB from the provisioned storage?

Also, when i type in 'sudo parted -l' :

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 64.4GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   64.4GB  64.2GB  extended
 5      257MB   64.4GB  64.2GB  logical                lvm


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/analysis--db-swap_1: 533MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  533MB  533MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/analysis--db-root: 29.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  29.5GB  29.5GB  ext4
```

Comment: I think the answer to this lies in the virtualisation software, not the Ubuntu guest... What steps did you take to provision 64GB, and then to specify 30GB?

Comment: I created 64GB .vmdk, and I think one of the step when installing the ubuntu server asks me how much do i want to allocate to it or something like that, and i put in 30GB eventhough i know that I have 64GB. I installed this ubuntu server a while ago, so i don't quite remember.. I have been trying to get the 30GB+ for this past few hours and still no luck..

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by refering to http://ezunix.org/index.php/Extend_existing_LVM_root_partition_without_rebooting. I just need to extend the logical volume, then extend the filesystem.

```
twadmin@analysis-db:~$ sudo  lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/analysis-db/root
  Extending logical volume root to 59.26 GiB
  Logical volume root successfully resized

twadmin@analysis-db:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/analysis--db-root
resize2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/analysis--db-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old desc_blocks = 2, new_desc_blocks = 4
Performing an on-line resize of /dev/mapper/analysis--db-root to 15535104 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/analysis--db-root is now 15535104 blocks long.

twadmin@analysis-db:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/analysis--db-root
                       59G   25G   31G  45% /
udev                  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 793M  228K  793M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1             228M   45M  171M  21% /boot
```